# Increment and Decrement quantity in ListView using react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am running sample project. I want to display the increment and decrement values. In my project increment and decrement values are not displayed. How to change the values in text.

Here is my code:

```
constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
         increment:0,
         decrement:1
    }
    }
  incrementFunc(){
        var countIncrement = this.state.increment
        this.setState({
          increment : countIncrement + 1
        },()=>{
          alert(this.state.increment)
        })
      }
      decrementFunc(){

            var countDecrement = this.state.increment

        this.setState({
          decrement : countDecrement- 1,

        },()=>{
          alert(this.state.decrement)
        })
      }

<View style={styles.arrowsView}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress ={this.incrementFunc.bind(this)}>
          <Image style={styles.arrowStyle} source={require('@images/up-arrow.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.numberView}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:15, color:'black'}}>{this.state.increment}
          </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.arrowsView}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress ={this.decrementFunc.bind(this)}>
          <Image style={styles.arrowStyle} source={require('@images/down-arrow.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
here is my screenshot:
```

[image]
Please give any suggestion. Thank You

Comment: Please edit your question and indent your code better. In current state its hard to read and understand whats going on.

Comment: When i was click on incrementFunc() that the value did not increment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution which i had made in my project , what i did

1. Firstly ->created an another component which will help us to have a quantity input functionality inside list element
2. Secondly ->This component needs to be called by the parent component inside list renderRow to make this component visible in all the rows.
   and put this QuantityInput component class inside the same file where you want to use it...
3. Thirdly -> Run yours application and have a look like this...

Have a look to the file attached...

```js
/*Use this component in yours parent view inside list to have a Quantity Input inside list , I have used native base as well if some thing gets miss please have native base in yours project...*/
{<QuantityInput item={this.state.data[rowID]} viewAddToCart={false} />}


/* QuantityInput */
class QuantityInput extends React.Component {
  userProductQty = Array.apply(null, Array(this.props.item.length)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 1);
  itemPosition = -1;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      viewAddToCart: this.props.viewAddToCart,
      item: this.props.item,
      style: { flex: 1 },
      styleTextInput: { backgroundColor: '#ffffff' },
      styleButton: { backgroundColor: '#000000' },
      styleImage: { width: 12, height: 12 },
      editable: true,
      stepsize: 1,
      initialValue: 1,
      min: 1,
      max: 100
    }
  }
  upBtnPressed = (dataSource, fieldName) => {
    if (dataSource.userQty < this.state.max) {
      let value = (parseInt(dataSource.userQty) + parseInt(this.state.stepsize)).toString();
      dataSource.userQty = value;
      this.setState({
        item: dataSource
      });
    }
  }

  downBtnPressed = (dataSource, fieldName, props) => {
    if (dataSource.userQty < this.state.min) {
      let value = (parseInt(dataSource.userQty) - parseInt(this.state.stepsize)).toString();
      dataSource.userQty = value;
      this.setState({
        item: dataSource
      });
    }
  }

  onChangeText = (text, item, fieldName, itemPosition) => {
    if (!isNaN(text)) {
      item.userQty = text.toString();
      this.setState({
        item: item
      });
    } else {
      item.userQty = 0;
      this.setState({
        item: item
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.viewAddToCart ?
        /* Add to cart */
        <View style={[{ flexDirection: 'row' }]}>
          <Left style={{ flex: 0 }}>
            <Button rounded danger
              title="Add"
              color="white"
              style={[{ width: 70 }, { height: 30 }, { justifyContent: 'center' }]}
              onPress={() => { this.props.onAddToCart(this.state.item); this.setState({ viewAddToCart: false }) }}
            >
              <Text style={[{ color: 'white' }]}>{string.addToCart}</Text>
            </Button>
            {/*</TouchableOpacity>*/}
          </Left>
        </View>
        :
        /* Quantity Text */
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <View style={stylesQuantityText.verticle}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.transparentBkg, { backgroundColor: '#d9534f' }, { paddingLeft: 10 }, { borderTopLeftRadius: 5 }, { borderBottomLeftRadius: 5 }, { justifyContent: 'center' }, { alignItems: 'center' }]} onPress={() => { this.downBtnPressed(this.state.item, this.state.item.productId); }} >
              <Text style={[{ width: 20 }, { height: 26 }, { fontSize: 21 }, { alignSelf: 'center' }, { paddingBottom: 10 }, { fontWeight: 'bold' }]}>-</Text>
              {/*<Icon name={"remove"} />*/}
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TextInput
              style={[stylesQuantityText.textinput, this.state.styleTextInput]}
              editable={this.state.editable}
              keyboardType={'numeric'}
              text={this.state.item.userQty.toString()}
              value={this.state.item.userQty.toString()}
              ref={"Qty" + this.state.item.productId}
              key={"Qty" + this.state.item.productId}
              onChangeText={(text) => { this.onChangeText(text, this.state.item, this.state.item.productId); this.props.onAddToCart(this.state.item); }} />

            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.transparentBkg, { backgroundColor: '#d9534f' }, { paddingLeft: 10 }, { borderTopRightRadius: 5 }, { borderBottomRightRadius: 5 }]} onPress={() => { this.upBtnPressed(this.state.item, this.state.item.productId); this.props.onAddToCart(this.props.item); }}>
              {/*<Icon name={"add"}
                size={27} />*/}
              <Text style={[{ width: 20 }, { height: 26 }, { fontSize: 19 }, { alignSelf: 'center' }]}>+</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>

    );
  }
}

const stylesQuantityText = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#eeeeee'
  },
  verticle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingLeft: 0,
    paddingRight: 0,

  },
  horizontal: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  textinput: {
    backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: 30,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    height: 26
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#dedede',
    padding: 5
  },
  image: {
    width: 18,
    height: 18
  },
  buttonText: {
    alignSelf: 'center'
  }

});
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNTbJ.png)